# Normed Division Algebras: Why those dimensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions, division-algebras, octonions

I recently read a fascinating article about string theory, which discussed higher-dimensional algebras and their applications to supersymmery. The author mentioned that there were only four algebras in which this was possible:

$\mathbb{R}$ (dimension 1),

$\mathbb{C}$ (dimension 2),

$\mathbb{H}$ (Quaternions, dimension 4),

$\mathbb{O}$ (Octonions, dimension 8).

My question is why does division not work in other dimensional algebras? What's so special about 1, 2, 4, and 8 that make this possible? I am looking for a high-level answer to this question, as I don't have much familiarity with algebra.